# Android studio 2.3.3 no palette

Tags: android-studio

Please I can't seem to find the palette in android studio 2.3.3 I've tried the view bar and I've restored default settings through the Windows bar, but still there is no palette outcome

Answer (score 0):

Left click on the "android manifest. XML" on the third tool bar , clik on "widget " ,this will enable the layout which you can use to get the palette